# How do I count the number of blank lines in a text file?

Tags: python, python-2.7, if-statement, lines, is-empty

```
import sys
import os
import glob
directory_input = raw_input("path to base directory?")
directory = directory_input

for folder in glob.glob(os.path.join(directory,"savedrecs(*).txt")):
    a = 0
    for file in glob.glob(os.path.join(folder, "savedrecs(*).txt")):
        a=sum(not line.strip() == "\n" for line in searchfile)
    print a
```

This is the code I have, but the a=sum(not line.strip() == "\n" part doesn't work and the result is always zero.

Comment: Can you show the full code, and the exact results? E.g. how are you doing the counting, how are you opening the file, how are you reading the lines.

Comment: `sum(not  line.strip() for line in f)`

Comment: Your first approach should work. Give an input file for which it does not.

Comment: What about "\n\n"  (how much you can find this string in the file )? And some logic for the last row (if the file ends with \n)

Comment: The problem is that the result always gives 0, but the files have many blocks of text and many empty lines that separate them. I can't see what the error is.

Comment: Do you *have* to do this in Python?  Your system command line likely has something that will handle this much faster, such as searching for "^$" with **awk** under UNIX/Linux.

Comment: `line.strip() == "\n"` will never evaluate to `True`, because the `strip()` will always remove the `\n` if it's the only thing left.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You never open a file and your glob pattern does not look for folders, it looks for files, just glob once on the user defined directory, open each file and `sum` the times `not line.strip()` evaluates to True :

```
import os
import glob
directory = raw_input("path to base directory?")


for fle in glob.glob(os.path.join(directory,"savedrecs*.txt")):
     with open(fle) as f:
         sm = sum(not line.strip() for line in f)
         print("{} has {} empty lines".format(fle, sm))
```

Comment: Thanks! One question, what difference does line.strip() and line.strip()=="" make, and what does the strip command actually do?

Comment: Both are equivalent, like when checking for an empty list, tuple etc.. You don't have to explicitly comprehension to an empty string , strip will strip any newline so if after stripping you have an empty string you know you have a blank line.